How to remove multiply dictionary keys from array of dictionaries in JavaScript?
I have
let Remove = ["Last", "Gender"];
let Contact = [{"First": "Bob", "Last": "Jim", "Gender": "M"}, 
                {"First": "Amy", "Last": "Christen", "Gender": "F"}];

How I remove multiple keys from the dictionary with the keys I want to remove stored in an array?
To get
[{"First": "Bob"}, {"First": "Amy"}]  

TS Playground

@HereticMonkey It was similar, but the answers seem to know beforehand what keys they want to remove. In this case, I did hard code the keys I want to remove, but I did it to make it simpler. I like Mr. Polywhirl's answer because it can work dynamically.

Nick Parsons's answer is good, too.

const res = structuredClone(contacts); for (const contact of res) { for (const removeKey of remove) { delete contact[removeKey]; } }

...and they'd all be better on the duplicate question, instead of on yet another repeat of the same question.

You can use .map() on your array to map each object to a new object without the keys specified in remove. For each object, you can grab the entries which you can then filter to remove the entries that have a key within your remove array. Once you've removed the entries you don't need, you can rebuild a new object by using Object.fromEntries():
const res = contact.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => !remove.includes(key))));



const remove = ["Last", "Gender"];
const contact = [{"First": "Bob", "Last": "Jim", "Gender": "M"}, {"First": "Amy", "Last": "Christen", "Gender": "F"}];

const res = contact.map(obj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => !remove.includes(key))
));
console.log(res);



TS Playground Link

You could map the objects and reduce the copy by removing keys.


const remove = ["Last", "Gender"];
const contacts = [
  {"First": "Bob", "Last": "Jim", "Gender": "M"}, 
  {"First": "Amy", "Last": "Christen", "Gender": "F"}
];

const removed = contacts.map(contact => {
  return remove.reduce((copy, keyToRemove) => {
    delete copy[keyToRemove];
    return copy;
  }, { ...contact });
});

console.log(removed);
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



Here is a TS implementation. You can use a Record<string, string> type to represent your object.
const remove: string[] = ["Last", "Gender"];

const contacts = [
  {"First": "Bob", "Last": "Jim", "Gender": "M"}, 
  {"First": "Amy", "Last": "Christen", "Gender": "F"}
];

const removed = prune(contacts, remove);

console.log(removed);

function prune<TObj extends Record<string, string>>(
        records: TObj[], keysToRemove: string[]): TObj[] {
    return records.map(contact => {
        return keysToRemove.reduce((copy: TObj, keyToRemove: string) => {
            delete copy[keyToRemove]; // Remove they key from the copy
            return copy;
        }, { ...contact });
    });
}


Another possible solution using forEach and for cycles:


let Remove = ["Last", "Gender"];

let Contact = [{"First": "Bob", "Last": "Jim", "Gender": "M"}, 
                {"First": "Amy", "Last": "Christen", "Gender": "F"}];

//Want [{"First": "Bob"}, {"First": "Amy"}]      
Contact.forEach((oneContact) => {
  for (let i=0; i<Remove.length; i++) {
    delete oneContact[Remove[i]];
  }
})
console.log(Contact);
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



